# Disappearing Reply, Reply-All, and Forward event handlers in Outlook add-in?

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I'm trying to catch events from my Outlook 2007 VSTO add-in when a Reply / Reply-All / Forward windows are activated. So I do this:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.Application.ItemLoad += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemLoadEventHandler(onItemLoad);
}

Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event gObj_itemEvt = null;

private void onItemLoad(object Item)
{
    gObj_itemEvt = (Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)Item;

    gObj_itemEvt.Reply += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_ReplyEventHandler(on_Reply);
    gObj_itemEvt.ReplyAll += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_ReplyAllEventHandler(on_ReplyAll);
    gObj_itemEvt.Forward += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_ForwardEventHandler(on_Forward);
}

private void on_Reply(object Item, ref bool cancel)
{
    //Called when user loads Reply window
    LogMessage("Reply opened");
}

private void on_ReplyAll(object Item, ref bool cancel)
{
    //Called when user loads Reply-All window
    LogMessage("Reply-All opened");
}

private void on_Forward(object Item, ref bool cancel)
{
    //Called when user loads Forward window
    LogMessage("Forward opened");
}
```

This works for a few times, but then stops. In that case, I'm still getting `onItemLoad` events, but `on_Reply`, `on_ReplyAll` and `on_Forward` are not broadcast anymore.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You define a single object as a source for the events like `Reply`, `ReplyAll` or `Forward`. It means only a single item can be opened to handle these events. Let's imagine the following scenario when two items are opened and the `ItemLoad` event is fired. In the case of the first item, everything went well and the source item is set correctly. But the second event leads to re-writing the source item, so you will not hold a reference to the first item any longer and don't get events for it. If you want to handle events for all opened Outlook items you need to maintain a list of objects instead of a single object reference:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.Application.ItemLoad += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemLoadEventHandler(onItemLoad);
}

List<Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event> gObj_itemEvtList = new List<Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event>();

private void onItemLoad(object Item)
{
    ItemEvents_10_Event gObj_itemEvt = (Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)Item;

    gObj_itemEvt.Reply += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_ReplyEventHandler(on_Reply);
    gObj_itemEvt.ReplyAll += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_ReplyAllEventHandler(on_ReplyAll);
    gObj_itemEvt.Forward += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_ForwardEventHandler(on_Forward);

   gObj_itemEvtList.Add(gObj_itemEvt);
}

private void on_Reply(object Item, ref bool cancel)
{
    //Called when user loads Reply window
    LogMessage("Reply opened");
}

private void on_ReplyAll(object Item, ref bool cancel)
{
    //Called when user loads Reply-All window
    LogMessage("Reply-All opened");
}

private void on_Forward(object Item, ref bool cancel)
{
    //Called when user loads Forward window
    LogMessage("Forward opened");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to try it. One question though - wouldn't I have a memory leak if I keep collecting all those objects in a list though? In other words, do I need to free/remove them at some point?

Comment: You cn subscribe to events like Unload to remove objects where and when required.

Comment: It works with collecting everything in a list. But for fixiing the memory leak, how would I know which object is being unloaded in the `Unload` method so that I can remove it from `gObj_itemEvtList`?

Comment: To distinguish items and their events you can develop an inspector wrapper, see [Implement a wrapper for inspectors and track item-level events in each inspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-implement-a-wrapper-for-inspectors-and-track-item-level-events-in-each-inspector) for more information.

Comment: I'm sorry. Can you show it in code how you'd use it? I'm not completely following you.

Comment: The article everything in depth. Did you have a chance to read it first?

Comment: I was replying to your previous comment that you editted out.